# How to UPDATE this statement by using ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have this set of data.

```
id | fullname | company | assign_num
1    sample2   company1   0000-1111
2    sample3   company2   0000-1111
3    sample4   company2   0000-1111
4    sample1   company1   0000-1111
5    sample3   company1   0000-1111
```

the assign_num is given.

and update the assign_num based on the company (ex. company 1)
    ex. 
    0000-1112, 0000-1501, 0000-1120

result will be like this:

```
id | fullname | company | assign_num
1    sample2   company1   0000-1112
2    sample3   company2   0000-1111
3    sample4   company2   0000-1111
4    sample1   company1   0000-1501
5    sample3   company1   0000-1120
```

using this codes it worked.

```
UPDATE myTable
JOIN (
  SELECT m1.id, COUNT(m2.id)+1 ord FROM myTable m1
  LEFT JOIN myTable m2 ON m1.id > m2.id AND m1.company = m2.company 
  GROUP BY m1.id
) z1 ON myTable.id = z1.id
JOIN (
  SELECT 1 ord, '0000-1112' assign_num UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 ord, '0000-1501' assign_num UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 ord, '0000-1120' assign_num
) z2
  ON z1.ord = z2.ord
SET myTable.assign_num = z2.assign_num
WHERE myTable.company = 'company1'
```

But I want the output look like this:
(ORDER by fullname ASC)

```
id | fullname | company | assign_num
1    sample1   company1   0000-1112
2    sample3   company2   0000-1111
3    sample4   company2   0000-1111
4    sample2   company1   0000-1501
5    sample3   company1   0000-1120
```

Comment: The expected result are not ordered by fullname.

Comment: but is it possible to ORDER BY fullname when execute. sample1,sample2,sample3 ?

Comment: It is already updated according to your specified sequence: `0000-1112(sample1), 0000-1501(sample2), 0000-1120(sample3)`. what do you expect?

Comment: @Dylan Su no see the 2nd table.  sample2 (0000-1112), sample1(0000-1501),sample3(0000-1120)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b33d13/1

```
UPDATE myTable
JOIN (
  SELECT m1.id, 
        IF(m1.company = @company, @rank := @rank + 1, @rank := 1) as ord,
        @company := m1.company
  FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY company, fullname) as m1 
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @company := NULL, @rank := 0) param
) z1
  ON myTable.id = z1.id
JOIN (
  SELECT 1 ord, '0000-1112' assign_num UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 ord, '0000-1501' assign_num UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 ord, '0000-1120' assign_num
) z2
  ON z1.ord = z2.ord
SET myTable.assign_num = z2.assign_num
WHERE myTable.company = 'company1';
```